# read apng (Animated PNG)

Tags: png

How to see those kinds of animations

---

Apparently Firefox support them, but isn't there a more dedicated software for that, a lighter one? A software dedicated to see a picture or something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firefox, for one, has no problem showing an animated PNG. eg. [Brain_MRI_apng](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/7e/Brain_MRI_apng_105px_100ms.png)

mplayer is another one. (and doesn't care about the extension, it will as happily an apng with and .IMoreOn extension).

Comment: It starts a download prompt if I open a local .apng

Comment: Check my URL, it's from Wikipedia.  The extension is ".png", not ".apng".  The original PNG specs had provisions for this extension.

Comment: Sure but I have bunch of .apng images, I just want to see them. Firefox doesn't support them?

Comment: Well, of course, you don't need to believe me.  Just change the extension.

Comment: It's not about beliefs, I want a software who can open .apng files and show me directly the animation

Comment: Why didn't you say so?  What's not "directly" about Firefox?

Comment: mplayer works just fine, thanks (your insult is not well fitted to this kind of context)